# Asp.Net MVC 4: Can we set Layout = null, when to Load Html Data from ajax Call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am adding another view page (with Ajax Request) into my existing view Page, like in this way -> $("divId").html(data);
Here data is my View Page which I am getting with ajax call.
My question is Can I remove 'Layout' or set it as Layout = Null, for this Ajax returned View page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In controller action you can return a `PartialView`, this will only send the HTML from the view to the client without the code from the Layout. You may implement your Action this way:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) 
    {
         return PartialView();
    }
    return View();
}
```

So you can use the same Action for a normal and an Ajax request.

Comment: A bit confusion, please clarify it- Does partialView() function automatically omits/leave the Layout contents or I need to create a new view as a partial itself to get the desired output? 
I am asking because, after return PartialView("myView") I am still getting the same previous output.

Comment: PartialView only returns the HTML from the view, without using the Layout. You shouldn't get the same output for an ajax request. Make a Breakpoint to see, if your action is going thru the if clause and returning the partial view.

Comment: Yes, with Break point I am seeing that it is going into if block (IsAjaxRequest), and returning Partial view, but still getting the view with Layout.
Need to clear one thing only, can a View(with inheriting any Layout), may be used as a partial view too? if No, then I need to create a new Partial view.

Comment: PartialView should not render the layout. Can you post your View? I define Layout in _ViewStart.cshtml and not within the view.

Comment: Actually this was the answer of my question, that We can not use a view for both "View" and "partialView" ( as you said - PartialView should not render the layout.)
Thanks for your valuable time. Now I am with actual approach.